# Code runs Speed Test CLI using the python wrapper and then stores values within CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, benchmarking

I wanted to make use of the speedtest-cli while also incorporating pandas into the project. My initial goal, which I am posting here, was to take the values of the speed test and incorporate them into a CSV. I've been learning about Pandas and figured it would be a good way to accomplish the project.

```
import speedtest
import pandas as pd
import os

# Initial Speedtest variables
s = speedtest.Speedtest()
servers = []

# File path variables
localpath = ''
filepath = ''
filename = ''

# Functions #


def speedtest():
    """Makes use of the speed-test-cli python wrapper
    to get speed test data and returns in a dictionary"""
    s.get_servers(servers)
    s.get_best_server()
    s.download()
    s.upload()
    s.results.share()
    results_dict = s.results.dict()
    return results_dict


def convert_mbps(arg):
    arg = arg / 1000000
    return arg


def csv_upload(localpath, filepath, filename):
    """Attempts to append a csv file and, if none
    exists, creates one in a specified path"""
    try:
        df2 = pd.read_csv(localpath)
        df2 = df2.append(df)
        df2.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath, filename), index=False)
    except OSError:
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath, filename), index=False)

# Speedtest and convert to Data Frame
result = speedtest()
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(result)
df2 = None


# Uploads CSV
csv_upload(localpath, filepath, filename)
```

I've tried as best as I could to document throughout my code, as well as to not statically specify parameters within functions; something which I've been bad for in the past. I've also tried to incorporate in some exception handling, though this is something that I believe needs more work in my code.

I've tested the code within a cron, it does exactly what it seems to be functioning as I would like it to. Future developments will surround analyzing data collected from the CSV; trying to determine trends in bandwidth or latency as a function of time of day. Any feedback would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use globals. E.g., you refer to `df` and `df2` in `csv_upload`, why not make them parameters?
2. Use the standard [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard around the script's main body.
3. It's common to just accept a flat file path, and expect the calling code to perform any `os.path.join` in the creation of said path.
4. "upload" sounds like network activity, but you're saving the data to disk. This should probably follow a more typical naming scheme of `to_csv` or `save` or `dump` or something of that sort.
5. This seems like a prime candidate for being a class.

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
import speedtest
import pandas as pd
import os


class MySpeedtest:
    def __init__(servers, initial_data_path=None):
        # Initial Speedtest variables
        self.s = speedtest.Speedtest()
        self.servers = servers

        if initial_data_path is not None:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(initial_data_path)
        else:
            self.df = pd.DataFrame()

    def run_test(self):
        """Makes use of the speed-test-cli python wrapper
        to get speed test data and returns in a dictionary"""
        self.s.get_servers(self.servers)
        self.s.get_best_server()
        self.s.download()
        self.s.upload()
        self.s.results.share()
        results_dict = self.s.results.dict()
        self.df.append(pd.io.json.json_normalize(results_dict))

    @staticmethod
    def convert_mbps(arg):
        return arg / 1000000
        # Actually, this should probably be "arg / (2**20)"
        # 1 MB = 2**20 B

    def to_csv(self, path):
        """Attempts to append a csv file and, if none
        exists, creates one in a specified path"""
        self.df.to_csv(path, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO: populate a list of servers, define localpath/filepath/filename
    tester = MySpeedtest(servers, localpath)
    tester.run_test()
    tester.to_csv(os.path.join(filepath, filename))
```

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that classes are a weakness in how I code. I have implemented some trivial examples, but don't often come to the conclusion to use them within my own code.

Considering that the initial script works fine, I'm assuming that a class would be useful within a project of a larger scope. Would you mind to give me a little bit of information on how incorporating the code into a class increases its usability?

Comment: It compartmentalizes your speedtest logic, including related state, into a single entity. Since the functions rely on sharing state back and forth, it seems reasonable to code them in such a way that their state is stored in a traditional fashion (as class instances). This also increases usability and testability by creating an entity that can be instantiated and exhaustively tested; when the code relied on global variables, it would've been difficult to rigorously test when embedded in a larger application (which could've changed the global variables between calls, for example)